# Haskell: Deleting a member from a tuple

Tags: haskell, tuples, sudoku

I am attempting to make a Sudoku solver in Haskell and am having issues making a deleteV function that will remove a value from the candidate list if a neighboring cell has the same value.  The board and cells are both defined by me, below is what I have so far:

```
type Cell = (Int, [Int])
type Board = [Cell]

rowNo  sq =  sq `div` 9
colNo  sq =  sq `mod` 9
boxNo  sq =  (sq `div` 9 `div` 3 ) * 3
    + (sq `div` 3) `mod` 3

-- Two squares sq1 and sq2 are in the same neighborhood if their row,
-- column, or box numbers are the same.

isNeighbor sq1 sq2 =
    ((rowNo sq1) == (rowNo sq2)) ||
    ((colNo sq1) == (colNo sq2)) ||
    (((boxNo sq1) == (boxNo sq2)))

delV val sq board =
    if board == [] then []
    else if isNeighbor (fst(head board)) sq -- then delV val sq (tail     board)
    then (val `delete` snd(head board)):(delV val sq (tail board))\
```

I can get delV to do part of what it should but not all.
When I call delV with "`delV 5 2 [(2, [1,5,7]), (26, [1,5,8])]`" I get
"`[[1,7],[1,5,8]]`" but the desired output is "`[(2, [1,7]), (26, [1,5,8])]`". While the only difference is the inclusion of the index in the output, I need it in this format. P.S. the current version of delV does not compile, in my attempts to fix it I have broken it more.

EDITED: Here is a version of delV that returns "`[[1,7],[1,5,8]]`" which is correct but does not include the index:

```
  delV val sq board =
    if board == [] then []
    else if isNeighbor (fst(head board)) sq then val `delete` snd(head board):delV val sq (tail board)
    else (snd(head board)):delV val sq (tail board)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some misformatted code and your desired output has a `7` where it looks like you wanted an `8`. I'll assume that this is what you meant:

```
import Data.List

delV val sq board =
  if board == [] then []                                         
  else if isNeighbor (fst(head board)) sq 
       then val `delete` snd(head board):delV val sq (tail board)
       else (snd(head board)):delV val sq (tail board)
```

where

```
delV :: Int -> Int -> Board -> [[Int]]
delV 5 2 [(2, [1,5,7]), (26, [1,5,8])] == [[1,7],[1,5,8]]
```

while you wanted

```
delV :: Int -> Int -> Board -> Board
delV 5 2 [(2, [1,5,7]), (26, [1,5,8])] == [(2, [1,7]), (26, [1,5,8])]
```

---

You can just add the indices back. Here's that, continuing your style:

```
delV :: Int -> Int -> Board -> Board    
delV val sq board =
  if board == [] then []
  else if isNeighbor (fst(head board)) sq
       then (fst(head board), val `delete` snd(head board)):
               delV val sq (tail board)
       else head board:delV val sq (tail board)
```

Here it is in terms of map:

```
delV2 :: Int -> Int -> Board -> Board
delV2 value square = map f
  where
    f (index, candidates) | isNeighbor index square =
        (index, delete value candidates)
    f t = t
```

Comment: `delete` is from `Data.List`.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I'll test it out as soon as possible and let you know if it solved the problem.